# Using group by in mysql, cause error 1055

Tags: mysql, pivot, mysql-error-1055

[image]

when I'm trying to use mysql to select the first form into the second form

```
select id, name ,
(case when years=1992 then cost else 0 end) as year1992,
(case when years=1993 then cost else 0 end) as year1993,
(case when years=1994 then cost else 0 end) as year1994
from pivot 
group by name;
```

I got a strange error

> ERROR 1055 (42000): Expression #1 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'nctest.pivot.id' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

What's the problem here?

-------------update--------------------------

I find I make a mistake using the group by.

```
select id, name ,
sum(case when years=1992 then cost else 0 end) as year1992,
sum(case when years=1993 then cost else 0 end) as year1993,
sum(case when years=1994 then cost else 0 end) as year1994
from pivot 
group by id, name;
```

then it works;;

Comment: Why are you trying to pivot the data in MySQL?  Your application should be able to use the original form quite happily

Comment: @eggyal it's the old database, we are migrating the old database into the new database,so it's a history problem..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to `SELECT` the `id` column but you can't because it's not in the `GROUP BY` expression.

Comment: but even if I add the id in the group clause, still got the same error.

Comment: Update your answer with the new error so we can see

Comment: i made a mistake using group by .now it's correct .